# Additional user information using EF5, MVC4 (with MVC3 AccountController) and ASP.NET Membership provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to build an MVC 4 app with MySQL as database and using asp.net System.Web.Providers, Entity Framework 5 with Code First approach. So far it's been hell!
I have made it work using MVC 3 AccountModel (since my mysql connector does not support the SimpleMembership yet).

So far users can be created, but I would like to have a little more information about the users stored in the database, e.g. what post they have authored, their website, etc.
For this purpose I have created a UserProfile class that stores this information.

How do I relate my UserProfile class to the asp.net auth-stuff, so I can get the extra user stuff, whenever I have my MembershipUser available?

Is the reverse possible?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information it is hard to answer your question.

In general regards to MVC3 Membership, it sounds like you would be best looking at a custom membership provider.  Try these for help

[Code Project - Custom Membership Providers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers)

[ASP.NET MVC 2 Custom Membership Provider Tutorial](http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/)

[ASP.Net MVC 3 Custom Membership Provider with Repository Injection](http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/)

or maybe the links in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263537/sample-code-for-creating-custom-membership-provider)

If custom membership seems over the top, you could try creating separate models that map to the UserProfile  as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316981/asp-net-mvc-3-storing-additional-user-information-in-tables-using-entity-framewo?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447313/how-do-i-integrate-membership-tables-with-entity-framework-asp-net?rq=1).

Hope this is helpful.